# Prime attribute and keys

Tags: key, 3nf, bcnf

Is a prime attribute only a member of candidate keys or can it also be superkeys? I am a bit confused as I am reading somewhere that a prime attribute can be a member of ANY key, and other says it needs to be a member of a Candidate key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prime attribute is a member of a candidate key.

In general, “key” is synonym of “candidate key”, while “superkey” is a “candidate key” together with other attributes (so, with this terminology, a “superkey” cannot be a “candidate key”).

A slightly different terminology, on the other hand, says that a “superkey” is something that determines all the other attributes (so, even a “candidate key” is considered a “superkey”). With this terminology, somebody talks of a *proper* (or maybe strict) “superkey” when it is a “candidate key” togetehr with other attributes.

So, in summary:

- a “candidate key” is a set of attributes that determines all the attributes of the relation and such that we cannot remove any attribute from it without losing this property (and on this definition *everybody* agrees)
- a “superkey” can have two different interpretations:
  a) a “candidate key” with zero or more other attributes; or b) a “candidate key” with other attributes.

Finally, when you find the term “key” alone, this is almost always a synonym of “candidate key”.

Comment: CKs are superkeys. Using "superkey" to mean a proper superset of a CK is incorrect use of the term. (I'd be interested in see refereneces to such uses in competent material.) Also, "key" alone quite frequently means superkey. For example in SQL constraints.